# How to solve external library causing JAR conflicts?

Tags: java, jar, lucene

I'm using `Lucene 5.0` in my application and I'm also using the [`DISCO` java library](http://www.linguatools.de/disco/disco_en.html), which does, in turn, use `Lucene 3.5`. When I import the DISCO jar I can't run the program anymore, because I get runtime errors regarding Lucene classes that are conflicting between the two versions of the library.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: No, I'm just using Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are three solutions:

1. You can downgrade your code to use Lucene 3.5
2. You can upgrade DISCO to use Lucene 5.0 (either yourself or by getting the DISCO team to do it)
3. You can use several `ClassLoader`s to isolate the code.

The last point works since two classes in Java are the same if the fully qualified name is the same **and** when they were loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.

The [OSGi framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) can do tricks like this. Eclipse uses Equinox, which is an implementation of OSGi.

One option is to bundle everything and set up OSGi to load things correctly.

To solve your problem yourself, you can create two `ClassLoader`s. One loads your application and Lucene 5.0. The other loads DISCO and and Lucene 3.5.

The ugly part is that you can now get `ClassCastException` for classes in Lucene. They will have the same name but they won't be the same as far as Java is concerned (different classloaders). To be able to pass data between the two classloaders, you need a parent `ClassLoader` which has POJOs in which you can put all the data which you want to share. `java.lang.String` will also be in this `ClassLoader` (otherwise, things would be very, very complicated).

Shared dependencies can also go in the parent `ClassLoader`.

You then need a thin adapter layer on top of the DISCO/Lucene code which allows you to do the operations you want without using any of the classes which this classloader doesn't like.